# onclick working, but stopped when running from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

So when user clicks on button an image will load..this works with the following code:

```
 <script type ="text/javascript">
        function showImg() 
        {
              $("#imagePreview").attr("src", "//this is a url for image");

         }
        </script>

        <div style="height:50px; margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:25px;">
            <img id="imagePreview" alt="" width="30" height ="30"></img>
            <input type="button" onclick="javascript:showImg()" />
        </div>
```

However I have tried to change it so the onclick button event is used on another pageso I have changed the above code to:

```
  <script type ="text/javascript">
        function showImg(url) 
        {
              $("#imagePreview").attr("src", "url");

         }
        </script>

        <div style="height:50px; margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:25px;">
            <img id="imagePreview" alt="" width="30" height ="30"></img>
        </div>
```

and on the other page i've added the

```
 <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="<%# FieldValueString %>" Text="View Image" Visible="true" />
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:showImg("<%# "FieldValue" %>")" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="No Image" Visible="false" />
```

But nothing happens when the button is clicked.
Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, should be: $("#imagePreview").attr("src", url);

Comment: just remove double quotes from url. Then check it. This means "url" should be changed to url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you took the parameter **url** as string... no need to use `""` in url

it should be

```
 function showImg(url) 
 {
     $("#imagePreview").attr("src", url); //here

 }
```